# Template strings in ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

What is the meaning of "passed array is frozen" in the context of template strings in ES2015?

Source: http://node.green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean any special in the context of template strings. It just means that the array [is frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isFrozen). From the docs:

> An object is frozen if and only if it is not [extensible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible), all its properties are non-configurable, and all its data properties (that is, properties which are not accessor properties with getter or setter components) are non-writable.

So the array of strings that is getting passed into the tag function is essentially **immutable**. This is supposed to allow engines to store it as a constant and repeatedly pass the same array object every time the tagged template literal is evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

You can define custom template literal tags in ECMA Script 6. For example,

```
(function(parts, a, b) {
  return Object.isFrozen(parts) && Object.isFrozen(parts.raw);
}) `foo${0}bar${0}baz`;
```

Source: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_literals

In the above code, the function object is the "tag" for the template literal.

When the template literal is evaluated, the tag function is called with all the parts of the template literal (in this case, they are `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`) as an array. The test case you are seeing is to make sure that array object is already frozen or not.

The test basically checks [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-gettemplateobject) of the ES6 Spec,

```
Perform SetIntegrityLevel(rawObj, "frozen").
...
Perform SetIntegrityLevel(template, "frozen").
```

Comment: Worth mentioning what a frozen object is - a frozen object is an object whose properties cannot be modified. You can create your own frozen objects with `Object.freeze` and check if an object is frozen through `Object.isFrozen`. Note that it's impossible to "unfreeze" an object. You can check it out in your console: `Object.isFrozen(Object.freeze({}))`.

Comment: So the function expression at the top of your answer is meant to signify that a hidden function expression is assocated behind the scenes with every template literal?

Comment: @BenAston Not every literal, just this template literal. If you want to use it with other literals, you can do something like this `const fn = ...;` and then "fn `foo${0}`"

Answer (score 0):

Templates strings are the ECMA6 concepts where we can write and append multiple line code with " ` " as before we use to do with double quotes with string concat.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var todo = {
    id: 123,
    name: "Pick up dry cleaning",
    completed: true
}

container.innerHTML = `
<div todo='$(todo.id)' class="list-group-item"> 
 <i class='${todo.completed}?"hidden":"glyphicon-ok"} text-success glyphicon'></i>
 <span class="name">${todo.name}</span>
`
Templates strings are the ECMA6 concepts where we can write and append multiple line code with " ` " as before we use to do with double quotes with string concat.
```

```html
  <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>
```